# After removing an item from an array it removes all duplicates entries - Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am making a shopping cart app with react-redux , and i am facing a problem. Every item in my list has an ID , but when I add 2 items with the same ID and then I suddenly removes them from the cart , all the items with the same id (aka duplicates are removed.Code below.

Reducer.js

```
   const reducer = (state = { items: [] }, { type, payload }) => {
  console.log(payload);
  switch (type) {
    case "ADD_ITEM":
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [...state.items, payload]
      };
    case "REMOVE_ITEM":
      const index = payload.index;
      return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.filter(({ id }) => id !== payload.id)
      };

    case "DUPLICATE_ITEM":
      return {
        ...state
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Action.js

```
const addItem = item => ({
  type: "ADD_ITEM",
  payload: item
});

const removeItem = (item) => ({
  type: "REMOVE_ITEM",
  payload: item
});

const duplicateItem = () => ({
  type: "DUPLICATE_ITEM"
});

export { addItem, removeItem, duplicateItem };
```

Item.js

```
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "projectile",
    price: "150$",
    units: 0
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "cute cat",
    price: "1250$",
    units: 0
  }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like the issue is more of a design problem i.e. rather than adding N of the same item to the cart, you probably want to increase the units/qty of the item if it already exists? Then when you remove, decrease the units/qty until it's reduced to 1 and then remove.

If you want the behaviour to work as is you would need to change how you remove from the cart e.g.

- remove by index rather than by ID
- create surrogate IDs for items when they are added to the cart and then remove by this

Comment: This sounds right, I will try it , thanks for the response.